# NPM packages: Deliver assets/images package

Tags: angular, npm

I created an (angular2) npm package and uploaded it to my (private) registry.

The component itself is pretty easy and should show an icon. Please see the template here:

```
<span
  [class]="'icon icon-' + key"
  [inlineSVG]="'./assets/icons.svg#' + key"
  aria-hidden="true"
></span>
```

As the path in [inlineSVG] shows, I would like to deliver the icons with the package. So I've put them into `./assets` folder.

But everytime I publish the package and import it into my application, I get a 404 that the file cannot be found:
[image]

I'm building my packages with gulp. I can post my gulpfile as well if needed.

Now my question: Is it generally possible to deliver assets (images) in an npm package?

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well technically no you can't because you might be able to upload the assets but the actual path changes. Your assets are not even served in the server to be honest since they are in the node_modules folder.

What you might be able to do is import the svgs inline in the css.
https://github.com/davidkpiano/sass-svg

Or otherwise include base64 uri of the image.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and precise answer!